# SQL Query - Need help to run the last query

Tags: mysql

```
with hotels as (
    select * from hotel_revenue_historical_full
    union
    SELECT * FROM projects.`db.2019`
    union
    SELECT * FROM projects.`2020`);
    select * from hotels;

    select stays_in_weekend_nights + stays_in_week_nights from hotels;

    select arrival_date_year,hotel, sum ((stays_in_weekend_nights + stays_in_week_nights) * adr) as revenue from hotels group by arrival_year, hotel;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem?

Comment: CTE can be used only in the query where it is defined in. So your further queries cannot access this CTE. Create temporary table with your CTE query as data source, then query this temptable.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
-- save the data into temptable
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE hotels
    select * from hotel_revenue_historical_full
    union
    SELECT * FROM projects.`db.2019`
    union
    SELECT * FROM projects.`2020`;

-- query needed information
select *, stays_in_weekend_nights + stays_in_week_nights from hotels;
select arrival_date_year,hotel, sum ((stays_in_weekend_nights + stays_in_week_nights) * adr) as revenue from hotels group by arrival_year, hotel;

-- drop temptable
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE hotels;
```

If the table `hotel` is not huge then you may add ENGINE = Memory to its definition which will improve the process.

Also I recommend you to use not `UNION` but `UNION ALL`.